# Determining a probability of a response variable value being true given a specific value for a predictor in R (binomial logistic regression)

Tags: logistic, binomial-distribution, random-effects-model, glmm

I've produced a binomial logistic regression using glmer in R explaining the failure response of O-rings in the challenger space shuttle with respect to temperature at the launch site.

Model:  model <- glmer(cbind(Failures, Successes-Failures) ~ 1 + Temperature + (1|Obs), family=binomial(link=logit), data = df.Challenger)

Where:
Failures = Number of O-rings failed during a given launch (out of a possible 6)
Successes = number of o-rings that did not fail during a given launch (out of a possible 6)
Temperature = Temperature of launch site during a given launch (in Fahrenheit)
Obs = Random effects variable

I want to determine the probability of more than 2 o-rings failing during the launch in which the space shuttle challenger exploded shortly after launch using the temperature of the launch site (31 degrees F). I'm very new to GLMs/GLMMs and do not know how to go about assigning a specific value to the predictor variable/a threshold of the explanatory variable to reach in order to deduce probability.

Any help is much appreciated. Should you need it, an image of the data should be attached.[image: Challenger Launches data frame excluding the fatal launch]